# Use different proxies depending on Squid server subdomain

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a Squid server hosted on DigitalOcean with a subdomain wildcard so every subdomain gets redirected to my server.

In my Squid config I have those 2 lines

```
cache_peer proxydomain.tld parent 20000 0 no-query no-digest
never_direct allow all
```

to redirect all the traffic to another proxy server, which works perfectly.

Now I want to redirect different subdomains to different proxy domains, so if you would use first.mysquidserver.com it redirects you to proxydomain.tld,
if you use second.mysquidserver.com it redirects you to anotherproxydomain.tld

I do not want to use different proxies depending on the site which got requested, I want to use different proxies depending on what subdomain gets used with my Squid server!

I didn't get any smarter with the documentation and Google. Not sure if this is possible with Squid? If not, would this work with something like NGINX? I know I could just redirect the subdomain to a different server, but that's not a good solution

Hopefully, it's clear what I want to say, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If You do not need specific feature of squid I would opt for a web-server like apache httpd (or even nginx, but not me...) as the configuration is more well-known and simple.
But it is of course possible with squid.

I assume You havce a recent (v4) installed.
Configured the http_port as accel.
Set up the different cache-peers (as origin servers or upstream proxy, depending on what they are).
Create ACLs for the dstdomains (one ACL for each cache_peer or cache_peer group).
Configure routing with cache_peer_access (define based on ACLs which ceche_peers are used for requests).